# how to adjust x axis when labels in x axis are getting hidden?

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly

I plot a graph using plotly package in R. I got the expected result but I'm facing a small issue. The plot looks like..[image: see here]

My code is:

```
plot_ly(input_file,x=~TimeStamp,y=~No_Of_Threads,type="scatter",mode="lines",name ="Virtual Users")%>%
add_trace(x=~TimeStamp,y=~ResponseTime,mode="lines",yaxis="y2",name="ResponseTime(ms)")%>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))%>%
  layout(                        
    title = "COMPOSITE TIMELINE",
    xaxis = list(       
      title = ""),     
    yaxis = list(        
      title = "VIRTUAL USERS")  
  )
```

But in x axis the time is getting hidden and being cut. How can I solve this so that the plot is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something with the `margin`-attribute of the layout: https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-margin
Set e.g. `pad` to 0 to reduce the distance of the ticklabels to the xaxis.
And set `b` e.g. to 200 (default is 80).
Im not able to test it cause I have no R. Hope it helps.

Comment: No it did not help.Is there any other way i can achieve my expected result?